# How to disable button once countdown date has expired

Tags: javascript, html

Please, how do I make HTML form button disable when countdown date expires, I was able to create a count-down date, but I don't really know how to disable the button once the count-down displays "expired".

```
// The output of the count-down date
<div class="value text-danger" id="demo"></div>

//html form button
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="your full name">
<button>Join</button>
</form>

// count down JavaScript
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Nov 22, 2022 11:34:38")  .getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " days remaining" ;
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give ID to the button and use this

```
document.getElementById(BUTTON_ID).disabled = true;
```

use this code:

```
    <div class="value text-danger" id="demo"></div>

//html form button
<form>
<input type="text" placeholder="your full name">
<button id="button">Join</button>
</form>

// count down JavaScript
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 22, 2022 11:34:38")  .getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " days remaining" ;
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the disabled attribute to "true". Can you try with the example below?

```
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    document.querySelector('#button').disabled = true;
  }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_disabled.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line in Jquery or Javascript whatever you want:

```
// in JQuery
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    $("#button").attr("disabled", true);
}

// in JS
if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    document.getElementById(BUTTON_ID).disabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set the `button's disabled attribute to true`.

```html
<!-- // The output of the count-down date -->
  <div class="value text-danger" id="demo"></div>
  
  <!-- //html form button -->
  <form>
  <input s type="text" placeholder="your full name">
  <button id="btn">Join</button>
  </form>
  
  <!-- // count down JavaScript -->
  <script>
  // Set the date we're counting down to
  var countDownDate = new Date("Oct 24, 2022 11:34:38")  .getTime();
  
  // Update the count down every 1 second
  var x = setInterval(function() {
  
    // Get today's date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
      
    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
      
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
      
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + " days remaining" ;

    let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance <= 0) {
      clearInterval(x);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      btn.disabled = true;
    }
  }, 1000);
  </script>
```